# need regex result integer only after parsing

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a number of exactly 5 digits from a string.

If I try

```
\d{5}
```

this works for `"12345"` or `"a12345a"`, but it also matches `"12345"` in the string `"123456"` which I don't want.

I can try

```
\d{5}\D
```

but then the string `"12345a"` will be matched in `"a12345a". Is there away to get just the number?

Comment: The proper way to post the last bit is as an answer, not part of the question.

Comment: Did you test out your regex? It doesn't appear as though it'd match `12345d`...

Comment: I don't have enough reputation!

Comment: `^D` means "start of string, followed by the letter `D`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a number of exactly five digits, even if it's surrounded by letters, use the regex

```
(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)
```

This matches five digits (`\d{5}`) which are neither preceded (`(?<!\d)`) nor followed (`(?!\d)`) by a digit.

Word boundaries (`\b`) won't work here because they wouldn't allow `12345` to match in `a12345a`.

See a demo on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/cR9bP2).

Comment: What if I can't assert? Is it impossible?

Comment: @AlexChap: What do you mean? I thought it was your aim to assert that no letter or digit follows after the 5-digit match?

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that it only works if I assert "mentally".Anyway My whole point was that there might be a letter after the number..like 12345a, but it will get only 12345 same for a12345a and a12345 and "12345". I hope you understand

Comment: Then your question is very misleading. You wrote "get a 5 digit number which doesn't end with a letter". I hope I understood now what you meant. Editing my answer...

Answer (score 1):

`(\d{5})[^a-zA-Z]` is the correct way.

`(\d{5})` is capturing is the 5 numbers and the `[^a-zA-Z]` says the next character can't be a letter.

**EDIT:**
For the sake of clarity: `\b(\d{5})\b` is used when you want to have 5 digit numbers that are surrounded by boundary's (tokens like `' , . "` and of course the space.

Comment: The new version should do the trick (or was my other solution what you meant?)

Comment: Also, note that [^a-zA-Z] does not even begin to cover the definition of "letter" unless you're restricting the input to 7 bit ASCII.

Comment: You one doesn't because it still gets me 123456 which I want only 5 number!

Comment: If you look at the second part of the answer, it says that way is used when you need exactly 5 numbers. The first part is an exact answer to the question, so 5 numbers not followed by a letter. (But i know that in your case you wanted the second part ;) )

Comment: The first regex fails if the 5-digit number is at the end of the string. `[^a-zA-Z]` says that there must be a next character (which can't be a letter).

Answer (score 0):

```
/\d{5}[^\d]/
```

This matches a sequence of five digits followed by a non-digit character.